# How to specify Local Date and Time in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, android, datetime, locale, android-notifications

I have an Android App and I wanted to display notification at a given date and time (all local). However if I use UTC format like this which I fetch from server thru json:

```
2016-04-14T11:30:00Z
```

the message gets displayed at the same time across the globe using this functions:

```
var mTime = new Date( element.dateNtime );
```

What I want is to display the message at 11:30 AM of local time everywhere. Like 11:30 AM in UK all the users will get the notification, but the users in the US will get the notification 5 hours later, i.e. 11:30 local time (EST or whatever).

### Update

I think I have found a solution, but from the answers below it appears that the question is either not too clear or is not understood. Here is the scenario:

a. My Cordova App is opened by the user on his mobile
b. The App reads a string date and message from the server at startup in this format "2016-04-14T11:30:00Z". So there is no question of getting current date using new Date() function.
c. Based on this the App sets up a notification for the given date and time using notification plugin of Cordova.
d. When the time comes the notification pops up

The solution is to use NON-ISO format for date, i.e. "'Wed, 09 Aug 1995 00:00:00'" along with Date.parse() function. Using the above example the code will become:

```
var mTime = Date.parse( element.dateNtime );
```

If the date is provide in this format ('Wed, 09 Aug 1995 00:00:00') variable mTime will contain exactly the same value. However if the datetime is provided in ISO format ( 2016-04-14T11:30:00Z ) then mTime will contain the time converted to the user's Locale.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using PHP server you can easily achieve by using below code:

```
$serverdate = date("d m Y");
$indiantime = date('d/m/Y h:i:s A', time()+19800);
```

Here variable 'serverdate' returns the current date of server , and  variable 'indian time' stores the time as Indian Standard Time

For converting time to proper zones use this formula
**x * 60 * 60**

Where 'x' is the GMT difference, In the case of India its 5.30
so 5.5 * 60 * 60 = 19800

Answer (score 0):

Just instantiate a new Date object

```
var now = new Date();
```

That will create a new Date object with the client's local time. To display like `8:30 AM`, use

```
var time = new Date().toString("hh:mm tt");
```

You can use `new Date().getTimezoneOffset()/60` for the timezone. There is also a `toLocaleString()` method for displaying a date using the user's locale.